# why fmt.Fprint didn't generate html output on the page?

Tags: go

Here's my code, fmt.Fprint outputs the source code on the page instead generates html output. What did I do wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

const AddForm = `
<form method=="POST" action="/add">
URL: <input type="text" name="url">
<input type="submit" value=“Add”>
</form>
`

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/add", Add)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8099", nil)
}


func Add(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, AddForm)
}
```

Comment: It did. But your browser did not render it but print the plaintext. You might want to set the Content-Type in the header to something more HTMLish. BTW: It would help if that code was an full HTML document, not just some snippet.

Comment: As @Volker suggest, add mine type OR add full html code. http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/sniff.go?s=648:690#L11

Comment: You can make it work by adding <h1>Enter below details</h1> on top of <form> tag. **hard coded**

Comment: Like the folks above mentioned, I changed the HTML and got it to display in my browser. Here's the full code: http://play.golang.org/p/EYDbh1Pxa4

Answer (score 1):

Adding the content-type and a `<body>` tag seems to solve the problem

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

const AddForm = `
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/add">
URL: <input type="text" name="url">
<input type="submit" value=“Add”>
</form>
</body>
`

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/add", Add)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8099", nil)
}

func Add(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, AddForm)
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/html")
}
```

Comment: Header().Set() can also be used.